# why when I join the same table by using alias, the row increase?

Tags: sql, join, duplicates, inner-join

I want to join the same table by using alias to find students who has the same name and take the same course. The below is what I do to achieve it:

```
select a.name, a.id
from student_takes a join student_takes b on a.name = b.name
where a.name = b.name and a.course_id = b.course_id
order by a.name;
```

The result table has more rows than the `student_takes` table. I expect that if I use `inner join`, the result table has at most as many row as the rows in one of the tables in from clause. When I use `distinct` keyword, the result table has less rows. I cannot figure out what are the duplicates in the above query?

Comment: Just to make query more clear I'd recommend adding `course_id` to your join too. Like this: `on a.name = b.name and a.course_id = b.course_id`. Also you can remove `where a.name = b.name and a.course_id = b.course_id` in such case. Just more clean code and less duplicate conditions verified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you're not including a condition that says, "and the other student is not me."  You'd need something like this (cleaning your JOIN and WHERE condition up):

```
select 
    a.name, 
    a.id,
    a.course_id
from 
    student_takes a 
     join 
    student_takes b on 
        a.name = b.name and
        a.course_id = b.course_id
where 
    a.id <> b.id -- assuming this ID is the student
order by a.name;
```

In addition, you could get multiplication.  Consider what happens when three students with the same name take the same course.

Three original rows:

> --> Student A
>
> --> Student B
>
> --> Student C

Matching the rows on "shares my name and takes my class but is not me" yields six results:

> --> Student A - Student B
>
> --> Student A - Student C
>
> --> Student B - Student A
>
> --> Student B - Student C
>
> --> Student C - Student A
>
> --> Student C - Student B

Notice that you have some logically different but practically identical results - student A matches to Student C, and then Student C matches to Student A.

Given that your original query is only retrieving data from the a table, you can kind of get around this with [a DISTINCT keyword](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp):

```
select distinct
    a.name, 
    a.id,
    a.course_id
from 
    student_takes a 
     join 
    student_takes b on 
        a.name = b.name and
        a.course_id = b.course_id
where 
    a.id <> b.id -- assuming this ID is the student
order by a.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find students with the same name taking the same course, don't use a `join`, use `group by`:

```
  select courseid, name, count(*) as cnt
  from student_takes
  group by courseid, name
  having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: how could you modify this to include student ID?

Comment: It does not work out because it only return the same students who take the course at least twice.

Comment: @user4147874 . . . Isn't that what you want?  Your question asks for "to find students who has the same name and take the same course".

Comment: @GordonLinoff The result return the same person who take the course twice. What I want is to return different people who happen to have the same name and study the same course.